# is reducing to normal form simply applying beta-reduction?

Tags: lambda-calculus

See example below:

reduce to normal form:

(λ c . (λ a . (λ d . (λ h . (h (d (a (a (λ z y . y))) (d (a (a (λ f x . x))) (a (a (a (λ z x . x)))))) (h (a (a (λ z y . y))) (a (a (a (λ z x . x))))))) (λ n m . n (d m) (λ z y . y))) (λ n m . n a m)) (λ n z . c (n z) z)) (λ z g x . z (g x))

Wikipedia says that to be in normal form: all reductions that can be applied have been).

I used these two calcualtors to try and get the correct reduction:
http://lambda.jimpryor.net/code/lambda_evaluator/
http://lambda.jimpryor.net/code/lambda_evaluator/

both return: 
λz x.z(z(z(z(z(z(z(z(z(z(z(z(z(z(z(z(z(z(z(z(z(z(z(z(z(z(z(z(z(z(z(z(z(z(z(z(z(z(z(z(z(z x)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))

Can I get to this answer by only using beta-reduction? This is the only reduction I am currently trying to understand but from this example there are two more:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34140819/lambda-calculus-reduction-steps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using only $\beta$-reductions is sufficient to get to a normal form **if** variables are named “correctly”.

**What do we mean by that?**

Let’s take as an example the term $\lambda x y. x\ y$.
Informally, it is a function that takes two arguments - variables $x,y$ and gives us the application of first argument to the second - $x\ y$. Now we want to apply something to this term, say $$(\lambda x y. x\ y)\ a$$

After we perform the $\beta$-reduction, substituting $a$ for $x$ in our term, we get $\lambda y. a\ y$ and we realize that whatever we substitute for $x$, we should be left with a function that applies it to the input variable $y$.

What if we want to substitute a variable named $y$ for $x$? We would be left with $\lambda y. y\ y$ which is a function that takes a variable and applies it to itself! Not at all the function we thought we would have for any $a$.

This example demonstrates that sometimes $\alpha$-*conversion* is necessary as a helper tool, and I emphasize the word “conversion” because it is not per se reduction.

---

You could also check my answer on [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/97008/reducing-lambda-expression-to-normal-form) that has computation similar in nature to yours and maybe try [pLam interpreter](https://github.com/sandrolovnicki/pLam) to see all the reduction steps with colored terms that go into reductions.